# How to limit oracle job interval for a particular day ,(Monday)?

Tags: oracle, scheduler, jobs

Hi i have to show one report and the report data should refresh on every monday.
automatically
I have checked oracle scheduler . i cant see any option for limiting the interval to  monday
.
I am thinking to give start date as monday and repeat 7 days interval .
is it good way

Comment: first time am righting a job so how can i right it hear i share my idea. there

Comment: I havent find the same question in stack overflow for oracle job

Comment: @davegreen why u have downgraded the question..

Answer (score 0):

Hi I got the answer.
YOU want to right like the code below.
There are 3 way for scheduling a job on every week day it can be every monday or another day
Here i have tried for running the job automatically on every monday 6 am

We have to set the frequency
either of the below code we can use

```
FREQ=DAILY; BYDAY=MON; BYHOUR=6; BYMINUTE=0; BYSECOND=0;
FREQ=WEEKLY; BYDAY=MON; BYHOUR=6; BYMINUTE=0; BYSECOND=0;
FREQ=YEARLY; BYDAY=MON; BYHOUR=6; BYMINUTE=0; BYSECOND=0;


begin
    dbms_scheduler.create_job(
    job_name           =>      'JOB_TEST',
    job_type           =>      'PLSQL_BLOCK',
    job_action         =>      'begin PROCEDURE_NAME; end;',
    start_date         =>       systimestamp,
    end_date           =>       null,
    comments           =>      'job is created for running automatically on every monday',
    enabled            =>      true,
    repeat_interval    =>      'FREQ=WEEKLY; BYDAY=MON; BYHOUR=0; BYMINUTE=0; BYSECOND=0;');
    end;
```

In oracle We can write jobs using DBMS Scheduler or DBMS JOBS
DBMS Scheduler is the above example and its the advanced one,
IF you want to Do the same Problem Using DMBS JOBS

```
    begin
      sys.dbms_job.submit(job => :job,
                          what => 'procedure name;',
                          next_date =>  NEXT_DAY(TRUNC(SYSDATE),'MONDAY'),
                        interval  => 'NEXT_DAY(TRUNC(SYSDATE),''MONDAY'')');
  commit;
end;
    /
```